# Retrieving emails from an exchange account... modify and resend

Tags: .net, exchange-server

I would like to create a .NET app that will connect to an exchange account... iterate through the emails in the inbox... modify that email and then forward it.

How would I begin to go about this? My first thought was to write an app that manipulates Outlook but Outlook is really just an exchange UI ;-)

THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look into [Exchange Web Services Managed API 1.1 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx)?